# How to create nodes from shell script at server?

Tags: drush

I need to create nodes from shell script at my server (some server statistics).

As I know **drush** cannot add new node. (It was a discovery for me)

So I think make shell script which will create CSV file with node fields and make periodical import by **Feeds**.

Is there more smart solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to start scripting on the command line, you can always script a php script and run it via drush. That way, you have access to your Drupal system and data. For example, if you place the following code in a file, e.g. script_create_node.php:

```
<?php

// Expect title as $args[1] and body as $args[2]
if( !isset($args[1]) || trim($args[1]) == '' || !isset($args[2]) || trim($args[2]) == '') {
  print "Expecting two arguments on the command line, title and body, for the new article\n";
  exit;
}

$node = new stdClass();  // Create a new node object
$node->type = 'article';  // Content type
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;  // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
node_object_prepare($node);  //Set some default values

$node->title = $args[1];
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $args[2];

$node->status = 1;   // (1 or 0): published or unpublished
$node->promote = 0;  // (1 or 0): promoted to front page or not
$node->sticky = 0;  // (1 or 0): sticky at top of lists or not
$node->comment = 1;  // 2 = comments open, 1 = comments closed, 0 = comments hidden
// Add author of the node
$node->uid = 1;

// Save the node
node_save($node);
```

you can always call this on the terminal like this:

```
drush scr script_create_node.php "Article Title" "Article Body"
```

You can extend such a script to include the logic you would use in your shell script, but instead of writing to a CSV file, you can write directly to the database. It's a great advantage having both PHP-CLI and a bootstrapped Drupal available at the same time.

Hope this helps some!

P.S: Lots of pages out there answering the question "programmatically creating nodes", one random pick would be http://www.group42.ca/creating_and_updating_nodes_programmatically_in_drupal_7

Comment: So `Drush` can add nodes (and much more) with `drush scr`! Thanks. It will take some time to test before I accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of right answers here; using feeds would work fine. You might also be interested to try [Drush Entity Commands](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity).

Comment: Drush Entitiy Commands are not regarded as save and D7 only

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `drush genc` if you have the `devel` module installed.  Old school but effective, creates fully populated nodes with randomly generated images etc.  (You can also use it to delete nodes as well: `drush genc --kill --types=NODE_TYPE 0 0`)

```
> drush genc --help
Create content.

Arguments:
 number_nodes                              Number of nodes to generate.
 maximum_comments                          Maximum number of comments to generate.

Options:
 --feedback                                An integer representing interval for insertion rate logging. Defaults to 1000
 --kill                                    Delete all content before generating new content.
 --languages                               A comma-separated list of language codes
 --skip-fields                             A comma delimited list of fields to omit when generating random values
 --types                                   A comma delimited list of content types to create. Defaults to page,article.
```